# Docx4j table column border has space in between using XhtmlImporterImpl

Tags: java, xhtml, docx, docx4j

I'm trying to convert HTML into docx using `docx4j`. I set `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes of table to 0. But somehow after I opened the generated document, there's still cellspacing between each cell. I used `XHTMLImporterImpl` to generate document. The following is the code I used:

```
String border = "border: 1px solid black;";
String testString = "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='" + border + "'>"
                     + "<tr>"
                     + "<td style='border-spacing:0;padding:0;background-color:red;" + border + "'>This is test row1 col1</td>"
                     + "<td style='border-spacing:0;padding:0;background-color:red;" + border + "'>This is test row1 col2</td>"
                     + "</tr>"
                     + "<tr>"
                     + "<td style='border-spacing:0;padding:0;background-color:red;" + border + "'>This is row2 col1</td>"
                     + "<td style='border-spacing:0;padding:0;background-color:red;'>This is row2 col2</td>"
                     + "</tr>"
                     + "</table>";

generateWord(testString);
```

`generateWord()` method as follows:

```
public static void generateWord(String html) throws Docx4JException
{
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert( html, null) );
    wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/output.docx"));
}
```

Result as below:

[image: Image of document generated using XHTMLImporterImpl]

There're whitespaces in between each cell.

Sidenote: If I used `CTAltChunk`, there's no spacing between each cell. But `CTAltChunk` cannot handle `Base64` image. I can use `<img src=''>` with `CTAltChunk` but it'll link the image source from the document. Once the source image is removed, the image will be gone from the document. That's why I need to use `Base64` image.